# Regular expression replace preserving groups

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way with regular expression to transform:
`M134.02,43.35c-12.62,1.4-29.25,6.59-39.85,19.65l15.35-5.82c26.24-18.1,54.45-10.65,62.99-0.11l1.27,1.34l0.02-0.04C169.6,49.83,155.11,41.01,134.02,43.35`

into:

```
["M", 134.02, 43.35],
["c", -12.62, 1.4, -29.25, 6.59, -39.85, 19.65],
["l", 15.35, -5.82]
// and so on...
```

I have currently set up this regex:
`([a-zA-Z])(-?(\d+(\.\d+)?),?)+`

But, replacing it with:
`["$1", $2]\n`

Takes only the last digit value, resulting in:

```
["M", 43.35],
["c", 19.65],
["l", -5.82],
["c", -0.11],
["l", 1.34],
["l", -0.04],
["C", 43.35],
```

Well, I do not need to do it in one regex (though, preferred), I am just looking forward to utilize IDE's `Find & Replace + Regex` to transform http://readysetraphael.com/ generated string paths to Array paths.

My IDE is phpStorm, so I guess it takes Java friendly regex patterns. I'm not Java developer though, so I do not know what extra options I have there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need such a specific regex.  Try

```
String s = "M134.02,43.35c-12.62,1.4-29.25,6.59-39.85,19.65l15.35-5.82c26.24-18.1,54.45-10.65,62.99-0.11l1.27,1.34l0.02-0.04C169.6,49.83,155.11,41.01,134.02,43.35";
s = s.replaceAll("(\\d)-", "$1,-").replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])([^a-zA-Z]+)", "[\"$1\", $2]\n");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
["M", 134.02,43.35]
["c", -12.62,1.4,-29.25,6.59,-39.85,19.65]
["l", 15.35,-5.82]
["c", 26.24,-18.1,54.45,-10.65,62.99,-0.11]
["l", 1.27,1.34]
["l", 0.02,-0.04]
["C", 169.6,49.83,155.11,41.01,134.02,43.35]
```

Comment: I need the commas before negatives too.

Comment: I would include that in the question and do it as a seperate step.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. Just wrap your second term in an additional braces to capture all numbers

```
([a-zA-Z])((?:-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?),?)+)
```

I changed the additional `(...)` to `(?:...)`, to avoid unnecessary capturing of subexpressions.

Test case for capturing groups:

```
public class CaptureTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "M134.02,43.35c-12.62,1.4-29.25,6.59-39.85,19.65l15.35-5.82c26.24-18.1,54.45-10.65,62.99-0.11l1.27,1.34l0.02-0.04C169.6,49.83,155.11,41.01,134.02,43.35";
        String t = s.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])((?:-?(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?),?)+)", "[\"$1\", $2],");
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

and the output

```
M134.02,43.35c-12.62,1.4-29.25,6.59-39.85,19.65l15.35-5.82c26.24-18.1,54.45-10.65,62.99-0.11l1.27,1.34l0.02-0.04C169.6,49.83,155.11,41.01,134.02,43.35  
["M", 134.02,43.35],["c", -12.62,1.4-29.25,6.59-39.85,19.65],["l", 15.35-5.82],["c", 26.24-18.1,54.45-10.65,62.99-0.11],["l", 1.27,1.34],["l", 0.02-0.04],["C", 169.6,49.83,155.11,41.01,134.02,43.35],
```

This is with `java -version`

> java version "1.7.0_03"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu2)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ See modified answer.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Never mind. A challenge is always welcome ;-)